# How to get out of a chrooted environment in ArchLinux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chroot

I'm attempting to install ArchLinux via SSH. At the moment I'm not at the machine, but I do have root access to it.

I have SSH setup in the Chroot environment (arch-chroot). Is there anyway, while being remote, that I can drop down to the root level below the chroot?